# How to find unique row other than null for the same ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, rdbms

I have a below table data  which contains status column with null and  `'Y'` for the `ID`

```
Id      Name    Status
1394    Test 1  Y
1394    Test 2  null    
1394    Test 3  null    
1395    Test 4  Y
1395    Test 5  Y
1396    test 6  null
```

`ID 1394` contains both `null` and and `Y`.
IF `ID` contains `Null` then I should not get that `ID`.

In This case I should get only `1395` because particular `ID` doesn't contain `null` value.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT Id, MAX(Status) Status
FROM tablename
GROUP By Id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Status IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Or if you want all the rows and columns use NOT IN:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM tablename WHERE Status IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.status is null
                 );
```

Comment: This is worked . what if my row contains lakh of data

Comment: @sampathacharya Is this premature optimization? Try it first. Or is your question just the beginning of a path to your actual problem?

Comment: @SMor ok i will try to get result .thank you

Comment: @sampathacharya . . . Odd that you didn't accept this answer, given that with an index on `(id, status)` this would have the best peformance.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT Id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Status IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

And one more option:

```
SELECT Id from tablename
EXCEPT 
SELECT Id FROM tablename WHERE Status IS NULL;
```

The first statement gets the set of all ID values. The second gets the set of all ID values where Status is NULL. EXCEPT removes the second set from the first as well as duplicates. Note that there is no ORDER BY clause so do not assume the rows have a defined order. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b9bd96c3e3ee7cbb51764721747f45a1)